# Java String to one type of character

Tags: java, string, character

Is it possible to replace an entire string with one type of character? Is there a method that will do this? One line of course.

```
Example:

"1234567890" turns to "xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use replaceAll:

```
String newString = origString.replaceAll(".", "x");
```

For example, this:

```
System.out.println("hello".replaceAll(".", "*"));
```

outputs:

```
*****
```

Comment: Nope. the first argument is a regular expression, and the dot is a wild card for everything pretty much... give it a try.

Comment: @Lion - why would I escape it? I want to replace EACH letter with an X

Comment: Are you waiting for a best answer? This's the better!

Answer (score 6):

A slightly more lightweight solution than the `replaceAll` one:

```
char[] chars = new char[origString.length()];
Arrays.fill(chars,'x');
String newString = new String(chars);
```

Oh, sorry, you wanted one line:

```
char[] chars = new char[origString.length()]; Arrays.fill(chars,'x'); String newString = new String(chars);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to replace an entire string with one type of character?

No, `String` is [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) and thus cannot be *changed* <sup>1</sup>, and thus you cannot "1234567890" cannot be *turned into* "xxxxxxxxxx"

You can create a *new `String` object*, which is replaced, as suggested by [@BinyaminSharet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422724/java-string-to-one-type-of-character/10422742#10422742)

---

(1) Technically, one can change immutable objects using [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) - but it should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: I guess you're technically right (lol, technicalities), but the other answer helped me out more.

Comment: Haha +1 for the precision even if it is most likely not what the OP meant!

Comment: @user1102901: Nevertheless, it should be emphasized. I linked to BinyaminSharet's answer because I would have used his solution to *create new Object*, and for this - I think his answer is great, and I have nothing to add on it.